# testing ssh key on host works fine but not in container with same keys

Tags: docker, ssh-keys

I have some ssh keys I use with github. Per [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection) page, I tested them locally:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi doug-companyname! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I'm running a docker-container and under volumes in docker-compose I have:

```
- ~/.ssh:/home/rstudio/.ssh
```

This is to give the container the same keys as local.

When I run the container if I look in ~/.ssh I do see the keys:

```
rstudio@9b5b5114115b:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh
total 12
-rw------- 1 1001 1001  452 Nov  7 19:35 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001  131 Nov  7 19:35 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 1001 1001 2212 Nov 15 16:50 known_hosts
```

These are indeed the same as the hosts, my local.
However, when I try to do the same test I get:

```
rstudio@9b5b5114115b:~$ ssh -T git@github.com
bash: ssh: command not found
```

Why are my keys not working in my container but they work fine on local?

Comment: Please share your dockerfile

Comment: I suspect that your image  does not have an SSH client installed by default.

Comment: Yep, just added `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh` and appears to be working now. Perhaps I should delete?

Comment: What to delete?

Comment: @Ashok He means whether he should delete his question, because he thinks it was a silly mistake (***NOTE: I personally do not believe that it was silly*** - we are all running into similar issues from time to time, and I would leave the question as-is).

Comment: I agree with you @Binarus because I too believe that it was not silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your image does not have an SSH client installed by default. Add the below line in your Dockerfile.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client
```